# How to convert multiple image in base64 and return in json format and display in html?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, base64

I want to convert multiple images into base64 and return in json format. At the same time, I want to display in my html templates. When I run my code it's works perfectly, but the result only display certain result only. Below I attach my result. I am also fail to display my json data in html templates. Here I attach my code.

[image]

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/api/images")
def get_images():
    directory = os.listdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')
    os.chdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')
    data={}
    for file in directory:
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        data["label"] = base
        open_file = open(file,'rb')
        image_read = open_file.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
        data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii') 
        final_data = json.dumps(data,sort_keys = True, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))
        print(final_data)
        #return final_data
        return render_template("images.html", final_data=final_data)
```

**Images.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>

   <ul>
    {% for data in final_data %}
    <li>{{final_data}}</li>
    <img src={{data.da}}>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code. First, you should collect all files and then return the template, but now your code returns after reading the first image:

**app.py**

```py
@app.route("/api/images")
def get_images():
    directory = os.listdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')
    os.chdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')

    flist = list()
    for file in directory:
        data = dict()
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        data["label"] = base
        open_file = open(file,'rb')
        image_read = open_file.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
        data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii')
        flist.append(data)     

    final_data = json.dumps({'files':flist}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    return render_template("images.html", final_data=final_data)
```

When you embed a base64image in a source of image tag in a html template, you need to mention that it is a base64image. So for Jpeg images for example, you can use:

**Images.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>

   <ul>
    {% for data in final_data.files %}
    <li>{{data.label}}</li>
    <li><img alt="embedded" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{data.data}}"/></li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot test if that works because I do not have the whole system, but I hope this gives you some hints.

Comment: I already put in my code but show error something like this 'local variable 'final_data' referenced before assignment'

Comment: you need to remove `print(final_data)` line, maybe @aminrd forget that.

Comment: @adam919191 That's because of line `print(final_data)`. I removed that line

Comment: @aminrd already remove and run the code and when i run localhost:5000/api/images the result show nothing, only display result result header

Comment: @adam919191 What are the file formats of your images? If not JPG, you should change it, or if it's a mix of png and jpg, then should automate

Comment: hi aminrd, all the image in images folder in Jpg format

Comment: i try to print flist.append(data) and it show display none result in my command prompt

Comment: @adam919191 Yes it shouldn't print anything. After the while loop is finished, you can test it with `print(flist)`

Comment: it's display the result.. but in my html still do not show any result

Comment: Hi @aminrd, I try print final_data.files[0].label but it's display result something like this 'str' object has no attribute 'files'

Answer (score 1):

> but the result only display certain result only

Put `return` inside for loop will exit the for loop immediately after first iteration. You need to make a list, then append new data on each iteration.

Comment: Hi @loginmind , I try print final_data.files[0].label but it's display result something like this 'str' object has no attribute 'files'. Currently, i still fail to display my result in html

Comment: Hi @adam919191, I found that in @aminrd solution, `json.dump` would return json format means it's string type.  That is why you got error `'str' object has no attribute 'files'`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still working on this.. but still fail to get the result

Comment: I still don't able to print the result in html..it's just display the header..but don't display the data

Comment: For working with problem like this, I suggest you working with mock data. You need to divide problem into two task: render html, and build data. Test each task with mock data first then combine them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207641/discussion-between-loginmind-and-adam919191).